# Spark dataset union resets class variables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have case class like this:

```
case class Ais(NotImportant)
  extends Serializable {


  var flag = Ais.Flag.NotFlagged
  var cluster = Ais.Unknown
  var visited = false

  override def toString(): String = {
    s"$cluster,$flag,$visited"
  }
}
```

After running my algorithm I'm ending up with two Datasets of type `(Int,Ais)` where variables in `Ais` objects contain information. I need to union them. The most important for me are the values of `var cluster` and `var visited`. Yet after `union` they are reset to default values.

```
labeledInner.foreach(println(_)) // This is fine
println("==========")
labeledOuter.foreach(println(_)) // This is also fine
println("==========")
labeledOuter.union(labeledInner).foreach(println(_)) // Here 
                                                // everything set to default
```

I'm running Spark 2.1 and Scala 2.11.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use mutable `vars` in case classes when using Spark - **these do not "survive" Spark's encoding**, so any non-trivial use of the Dataset (like using `union`) which triggers encoding and decoding would not preserve these fields.

**Why**? Spark has built-in Encoders that are meant to efficiently encode objects into byte-arrays (and back). For case classes (actually, for all `Product`s, which mostly means case classes and tuples), the encoders only encode the case-class **fields** that are defined as class parameters (in your case, only `NotImportant`). You can see this by creating the relevant encoder for your case class and checking its *schema*:

```
case class A(s: String) {
  var a: Int = 0
}

Encoders.product[A].schema.printTreeString()
// root
// |-- s: string (nullable = true)
```

As you can see - only `s` survived, `a` is not part of the schema.

**What's the alternative**? When using Spark (and really, Scala in general), you should refrain from *mutable* fields. Try modeling your data to contain all fields as immutable fields, e.g.:

```
case class Ais(flag: Flag, cluster: Cluster, visited: Boolean)
```

Then, to "mutate" these objects, you can use the `copy` method that creates a new instance with some (or none) of the fields changed, e.g.:

```
val a = Ais(Ais.Flag.NotFlagged, Ais.Unknown, false)
val b = a.copy(visited = true)
```

These objects will be safe to use with Spark (they "survive" serialization and are immutable).

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my suspicions. Is there a way to preserve the mutable variables state with some other encoder, like kryo?